# How do I add a margin to a stroke in a custom drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a drawable which is a circle with a stroke. How do I add a margin to that stroke?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I've tried adding another `<item>` with a stroke but that doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>  
    <stroke
         android:width="3dp"
         android:color="@android:color/blue" />
       
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Also tried adding it in the same `<shape/>` tag

```
<item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/blue" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

I've also tried adding `dp` to the `<item>` tag

```
<item
        android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:right="6dp">
```

but that only creates margin from the viewport to the drawable

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind, could you please add an image to what you exactly want to achieve, so we can help you

Comment: hi, yeah what I want is the image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

For the second one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gradientRadius="20"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="8dp"
                android:color="@android:color/red" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gradientRadius="20"
                android:startColor="@android:color/black" />

            <stroke
                android:width="8dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that worked! how about if I wanted to do something like this?
https://i.imgur.com/1yv98Di.png I tried reversing the two ```<item>``` tag but it wouldn't work

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE is that a white color or transparent ?

Comment: transparent color

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE I've updated my answer, I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That works! thank you so much for your help. I was trying for two hours trying to figure both out.

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE you're welcome my friend